# Did Harry Truman's nephew appear in the original Twin Peaks?

Tags: character, twin-peaks

In the new Showtime revival of [Twin Peaks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4093826/), the sheriff of Twin Peaks is now Frank Truman, who is filling in for his brother Harry Truman who has fallen sick (*This is because Michael Ontkean, the actor who played Harry Truman, refused to reprise his role*).

We see multiple instances of Frank's wife storming into the Sheriff station and getting irrationally angry at anything that Frank says. We finally learn the reason - she used to be a loving wife, but then their son committed suicide after suffering [PTSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder) from serving in war.

My question is, **did this son ever appear in the original series?**

The reason I ask is that I vaguely remember a relative of Harry being one of the Bookhouse Boys (*a secret society that protects Twin Peaks from the darkness in the woods*). I think this relative was Harry's nephew, but I could be mis-remembering things.

Answer (score 2):

### No. We never see him.

I'm not sure who you mis-remember as being Harry's relative, but might it be [Cappy](http://twinpeaks.wikia.com/wiki/Cappy)?